# JS field rendering return standard field rendering

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jslink

how can return the standard rendering of a field?

```
(function () {

    var readonlyFiledContext = {};
    readonlyFiledContext.Templates = {};
    readonlyFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        // Apply the new rendering for Age field on Edit forms
        "Title": {
            "EditForm": FieldTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(FiledContext);

})();

function FieldTemplate(ctx) {

     return ;
    }
}
```

It depends on the value I like to render the filed. When the value is not null then make it fancy and when it is equals “null” then render like the standard rendering. How I can in this code segment return the standard field rendering?

Thanks for help
Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to render text field using  default rendering template if value is not empty:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      Templates: {

           Fields: {
               "ReqNo": {
                   EditForm: renderRegNo,
               }
           }
      }

    });

});

function renderRegNo(ctx){
  if(ctx.CurrentItem.RegNo.length == 0) {
       return "Request number is missing";
  }
  return SPFieldText_Edit(cxt); 
}
```

> Note: it is assumed that the  `RegNo` field is of `Text` type

---

`clientforms.js` contains the list of default field rendering templates (*per field type*):

```
var spfieldCtx = {
            Templates: {
                Fields: {
                    'Text': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldText_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldText_Edit
                    },
                    'Number': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
                    },
                    'Integer': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
                    },
                    'Boolean': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_DefaultNoEncode,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldBoolean_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldBoolean_Edit
                    },
                    'Note': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldNote_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNote_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNote_Edit
                    },
                    'Currency': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
                    },
                    'File': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldFile_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldFile_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldFile_Edit
                    },
                    'Calculated': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Empty,
                        'NewForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Empty
                    },
                    'Choice': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldChoice_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldChoice_Edit
                    },
                    'MultiChoice': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldMultiChoice_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldMultiChoice_Edit
                    },
                    'Lookup': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldLookup_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit
                    },
                    'LookupMulti': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldLookup_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit
                    },
                    'Computed': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'NewForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default
                    },
                    'URL': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldUrl_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldUrl_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldUrl_Edit
                    },
                    'User': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldUser_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate,
                        'NewForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate
                    },
                    'UserMulti': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldUserMulti_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate,
                        'NewForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate
                    },
                    'DateTime': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldDateTime_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldDateTime_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldDateTime_Edit
                    },
                    'Attachments': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to return a readonly value for a User field, you need to format the results before returning it (SPFieldUser_Display won't return anything).

```
function prepareUserFieldValue(ctx) {
    var item = ctx['CurrentItem'];
    var userField = item[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    var fieldValue = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < userField.length; i++) {
        fieldValue += userField[i].EntityData.SPUserID + SPClientTemplates.Utility.UserLookupDelimitString + userField[i].DisplayText;

        if ((i + 1) != userField.length) {
            fieldValue += SPClientTemplates.Utility.UserLookupDelimitString
        }
    }

    ctx["CurrentFieldValue"] = fieldValue;
}
```

Thanks to http://sp77.blogspot.com/2017/07/client-side-rendering-csr-in-sharepoint.html

You can call it like this:

```
ReadOnlyUserField = function(ctx) {
    prepareUserFieldValue(ctx)
    return SPFieldUser_Display(ctx);

};
```

Hope that helps someone!  (Probably me in 6 months when I've completely forgotten this)

Answer (score 0):

Another option using SPCSR helper - https://github.com/sdaly2107/SPCSR_Helper

SPCSR.Utils.HookFieldTemplates({

```
'ReqNo': function(ctx, template) {

 if(ctx.CurrentItem.RegNo.length == 0) {
        template.html "Request number is missing";
 }

}
```

}